# How do i track one word in a URL in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

```
event/register?_qf_ThankYou_display=true&qfKey=d0
```

Trying to create a goal with regex with only "ThankYou" to track a goal it's its not happening. Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because its not programming related its about setup in the google analytics website probably better suited for https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

Select the `RegEx` option. GA Goal Setup:

[image]